How to force Quarkus include both javax.activation and jakarta libs into uber jar
I have legacy SDK which requires javax.activation dependency. Unfortunately, when I build Quarkus 3.15 uber jar it doesn't include javax.activation into uber.jar
I figured out Quarkus 2.5.4 includes javax.activation dependency but then doesn't include jakarta dependency and fails on start
Is there a way to force Quarkus (quarkus-maven-plugin) to include both dependencies?
I found this thread which says

Quarkus extensions may define artifacts that should always be excluded
From the build


The most straightforward way is maven-antrun-plugin
You can do something like
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>repackage-jar</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <target>
                        <move file="target/${project.build.finalName}-runner.jar"
                              tofile="target/${project.build.finalName}-runner-original.jar"/>

                        <mkdir dir="target/tmp"/>
                        <unzip src="lib/javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar" dest="target/tmp"/>
                        <delete dir="target/tmp/META-INF"/>
                        <unzip src="target/${project.build.finalName}-runner-original.jar" dest="target/tmp"/>

                        <zip destfile="target/${project.build.finalName}-runner.jar">
                            <fileset dir="target/tmp"/>
                        </zip>

                        <delete dir="target/tmp"/>
                    </target>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

If you need only this lib then that's it but probably you have more complicated case right now or in the near future you will need something else. In my case, I also need jaxb and a couple of other libs so finally I must either manually pack each library or look for other solutions. In the end, I downgraded Quarkus to version 2.5.4.FINAL and it helped me.
Also, I must say don't use maven-shade-plugin It doesn't fit Quarkus. Shade plugin breaks Quarkus uber jar so it doesn't start even activation.jar was successfully copied inside uber.jar
Anyway here is the shade plugin config even though I don't recommend using it
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>

                            <shadedArtifactAttached>false</shadedArtifactAttached>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/versions/21/**</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>my.package.MyApplication</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                            <finalName>${project.build.finalName}-runner</finalName>

                            <relocations>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>javax.activation</pattern>
                                    
   <shadedPattern>shaded.javax.activation</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                            </relocations>
                            <minimizeJar>false</minimizeJar>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

